# PyQt5 and OpenCV have similar libraries; how to avoid conflict between the 2?

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5, conda

I have PyQt5 and OpenCV in the same conda virtual environment.

```
opencv-python==3.4.1.15    
PyQt5==5.10.1
```

Whenever I run my PyQt5 app, I get many warnings like these:

```
objc[7992]: Class QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate is implemented in both /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x109ae0290) and /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x10a387f20). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7992]: Class QCocoaPrintPanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x109ae0308) and /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x10a387f70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.    
objc[7992]: Class QCocoaApplicationDelegate is implemented in both /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x109ae0010) and /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x10c6ed480). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.    
objc[7992]: Class QNSApplication is implemented in both /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x109adffc0) and /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x10c6ed4d0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.    
objc[7992]: Class QCocoaMenuLoader is implemented in both /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x109adff70) and /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x10c6ed570). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.    
objc[7992]: Class QNSImageView is implemented in both /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x109ae0330) and /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x10c6ed660). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.    
objc[7992]: Class QNSStatusItem is implemented in both /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x109ae0380) and /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x10c6ed6b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.    
objc[7992]: Class QNSOpenSavePanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x109ae0150) and /Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/qacker/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x10c6ed750). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

What is the appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: I am having similar problem on mac with PyQt and opencv. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: did you guys find a solution? @PunitSoni

Comment: @sona no. The question was also posted to the QtForum but this forum currently appears to be down: https://forum.qt.io/topic/93012/how-do-i-specify-which-of-2-versions-of-the-qt-libs-should-be-used

Comment: I am facing the same issue. did you guys find a solution?

Answer (score 14):

I solved the problem by uninstalling opencv with the GUI and installing the headless version:

pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless

The namedWindow function in opencv still works.

Comment: I've just replicated this and tested what you suggested and it worked, So it's a +1 from me.

Comment: I searched a lot about this question and many answers are too complex. This one is simple and worked.

Comment: Solved the issue for me as well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved the problem removing opencv-python

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

and then installing opencv-headless

```
pip3 install opencv-python-headless
```

After that, my application run again.