# How to deal with classes implemented in both Cv2/.dylibs/QTGui and LibQcocoa/ LibQt5Print Support?

Tags: python, anaconda, opencv, dylib, qtgui

I am trying to implement Mask RCNN on a dataset of images and my code halts with error messages. These 8 Classes are implemented in two different locations on my computer and the computer is telling me to pick one; however, I cannot understand how to select one (or which to select). ***I'm only in HS, so I truly need all the help I can get!:)***

I am running this on a Mac in Eclipse with Anaconda 3.

```py
visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], dataset.class_names, r['scores'], ax=get_ax(1), title="Predictions")
```

This line is where these classes are called from. The program is able to call the function and outputs the metadata:

```
image                    shape: (736, 700, 3)         min:    0.00000  max:  255.00000  uint8
molded_images            shape: (1, 1472, 1408, 3)    min:  -48.22000  max:  214.44000  float64
image_metas              shape: (1, 14)               min:    0.00000  max: 1472.00000  float64
anchors                  shape: (1, 517638, 4)        min:   -0.06433  max:    1.01884  float32
```

but then it halts due to the error:

```
objc[1408]: Class QCocoaPrintPanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x1c400c8638) and /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.5.9.7.dylib (0x129f55f40). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1408]: Class QCocoaApplicationDelegate is implemented in both /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x1c400c8340) and /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1c439e2670). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1408]: Class QNSApplication is implemented in both /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x1c400c82f0) and /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1c439e26c0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1408]: Class QCocoaMenuLoader is implemented in both /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x1c400c82a0) and /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1c439e2760). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1408]: Class QNSImageView is implemented in both /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x1c400c8660) and /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1c439e2850). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1408]: Class QNSStatusItem is implemented in both /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x1c400c86b0) and /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1c439e28a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1408]: Class QNSOpenSavePanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x1c400c8480) and /Users/myName/py3env/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1c439e2940). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Side note: I do not have XCode downloaded at this point. Many answers to related questions have pinpointed the problem to xCode, but I do not have the actual application, just libraries that came on the Mac. UPDATE: I downloaded XCode to see if it would help, but this problem persists.

*** a similar question is at [PyQt5 and OpenCV have similar libraries; how to avoid conflict between the 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371421/pyqt5-and-opencv-have-similar-libraries-how-to-avoid-conflict-between-the-2/52397814) however, there is no answer so I tried to phrase this more concisely. Thanks!